# Can a stateful DoFn have state that expires with a TTL? Or is unbounded growth OK?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a situation in Apache Beam (running in Dataflow) where I have created a simple stateful DoFn, based on [this article](https://beam.apache.org/blog/stateful-processing/). The upstream window is global, and changing it would impact downstream aggregations.

Currently, I am not doing anything to shrink the state, and it would appear to just grow unbounded. Is this true? Is unbounded state growth a problem?

I would like to simply attach a TTL to the state, but don't see this functionality.

I am considering storing my own timestamp on the data, and using a timer to cleanup the table periodically. Is this advisable?

The data that's being stored is a cache key on some evented data. The cache key tells me that I need to lookup a past events data for this event to hydrate the current event. The stateful DoFn works well for this, yet, like I said I am concerned it will grow unbounded. I'm unsure if there's any consequences of that in Dataflow.

Answer (score 2):

State is automatically garbage collected when a window expired. Since you are using the global window, it will never expire. So you will need to manage this yourself with timers.

I don't know the details of your code but your idea sounds about right:

- store a timestamp with your state so you know how old it is
- set an event time timer that repeats periodically:

  - clean up things in the table older than TTL
  - the `@OnTimer` method can reset the same timer

You could also directly set a timer for the TTL for an element, but that will cause many more timers to fire. So would only be good if volume is low. (but if volume is low you probably don't have to worry about unbounded growth so much)

Comment: Hi! We are using this object (StateSpec<ValueState<Boolean>>) to store the processed keys of our <K,V> elements in the pipeline. If we use event time processing, will be this state object garbage collected automatically only for the events in the windows that expired? (without clearing any later event in the subsequent window). (If not, is there an object like the one we are using that can be cleared with a TTL (i.e clear only the olders event in the statr without clearing all of them)