# Apache beam: TTL in State Spec

Tags: apache-flink, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, amazon-kinesis

We are reading from Kinesis and writing to parquet and we use `StateSpec<ValueState<Boolean>>` to avoid duplicated processing of records after gracefully stopping and relaunching our pipeline from the last savepoint.

We saw that some records were duplicated because they end up falling on a different task manager on subsequent relaunches, and we use `StateSpec<ValueState<Boolean>>` to store stateful information about the processed records and avoid duplicates.

We are dealing with how to clear the state every certain time without the risk of losing the most recent processed records if they are needed in an upcoming stop. (i.e, we need a something like a TTL on that class).

We thought about a timer that clears the state every certain time but that doesn't meet our requirements because we need to keep the most recent processed records.

We read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66247993/can-a-stateful-dofn-have-state-that-expires-with-a-ttl-or-is-unbounded-growth-o) that using event time processing automatically clears State information after a window expires and we would like to know if that fits with our requirement using the `StateSpec` class.

Otherwise, is there a class to store state that has a kind of TTL to implement this feature?

What we have right now is this piece of code that checks if the element has already processed and a method that clears the state every certain time

```
    @StateId("keyPreserved")
    private final StateSpec<ValueState<Boolean>> keyPreserved = StateSpecs.value(BooleanCoder.of());
    @TimerId("resetStateTimer")
    private final TimerSpec resetStateTimer = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.PROCESSING_TIME);

    public void processElement(ProcessContext context,
        @TimerId("resetStateTimer") Timer resetStateTimer,
        @StateId("keyPreserved") ValueState<Boolean> keyPreservedState) {
        if (!firstNonNull(keyPreservedState.read(), false)) {
            T message = context.element().getValue();

            //Process element here

            keyPreservedState.write(true);
        }
    }


    @OnTimer("resetStateTimer")
    public void onResetStateTimer(OnTimerContext context,
        @StateId("keyPreserved") ValueState<Boolean> keyPreservedState) {
        keyPreservedState.clear();
    }
```

Comment: The [example under Event-Time-Timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/#Event-Time-Timers) could be used to achieve `using event time processing automatically clears State information after a window expires`. Your example code seems to be missing how you configure the timer and it should be this [example under Processing-Time-Timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/#Processing-Time-Timers).

Comment: Yes, we follow that post and we think that calling clear() on the ValueState object would clear the whole cache. Then we figured out that it will only clear the element in the contexts. If we understood well the last behaviour (clearing only 1 element) should be find to get a TTL whereas clearing the whole cache not. But we tried that and we are still having duplicated records

Comment: On the other side, we are not using event time at this moment,we are using processing time. The question was if the state is automatically cleared when the window expires, and only the state related to that window. If we use the approach you mention and make a clear() of the cache certain time after expiration, we are in the same scenario (dealing  with clearing the whole cache  -an we don't want it-, or maybe not?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the timer every time we call `keyPreservedState.write(true);` was enough. When the timer expires  `keyPreservedState.clear();` only clears the element in the contexts, not the whole state.