# AWS Flink (KDA) rocks db checkpoint size is increasing and never comes down

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, rocksdb, amazon-kinesis-analytics

In our application , flink checkpoint size is increasing and never comesdown with rocks db as statebackend.(AWS KDA)

```
Kafka-->do some magic -->ES(Sink)-->Writes to kafka
```

here the keys we use are UUID and are never repeated. How can i configure to make sure that the check point size is not increasing or finetune rocks db to delete any older keys less than 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

With the DataStream API you can configure [state TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) to automatically delete keys after some time interval, or you can manage state expiry manually by using timers in a KeyedProcessFunction.

If you are using the SQL/Table API, then you should configure an [idle state retention time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/query_configuration.html#idle-state-retention-time).

Comment: i am using apache beam as coding sdk..need help how to do this in beam

Comment: I believe beam has timers you can use for this purpose. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349543/apache-beam-ttl-in-state-spec, for example.